# Retrieve values from a table without using filters

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables

**Estatus table**

```
+----+----------+
| ID |  Nombre  |
+----+----------+
| 16 | ACTIVE   |
|  2 | DISABLED |
+----+----------+
```

**TipoCarga Table**

```
+----+----------+--------------------+-----------+
| ID |  Nombre  |    Descripcion     | EstatusID |
+----+----------+--------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Active   | first descriptio   |        16 |
|  2 | Disabled | second description |         2 |
+----+----------+--------------------+-----------+
```

and I have custom entity to list and charge like:

```
 IEnumerable<T> Listar(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "");

        T Cargar(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter,
            string includeProperties = "");
```

if I do something like

```
var claseid = _claseService.Cargar(c => c.Nombre.Equals("TIPOS DE CARGA")).ID;
var estatusid = _estatusService.Cargar(e => e.Nombre.Equals("ACTIVE") && e.ClaseID.Equals(claseid)).ID;
var tc = _tipoCargaService.Listar(c => c.EstatusID.Equals(estatusid), includeProperties: "Estatus");
```

It load values, but only values who have `Nombre.Equals("ACTIVO")`, and I want to get all `Nombre` values

So first I try to get a list of all Estatus like:

```
    //I don´t need this line because I dont wannt to filte by clase
    //var claseid = _claseService.Cargar(c => c.Nombre.Equals("TIPOS DE CARGA")).ID;

       //get list of all estatus
      var estatusid = _estatusService.Listar();
```

then use this list and use to retrieve value "Nombre" depending of EstatusID of table TipoCarga like:

```
var tc = _tipoCargaService.Listar(c => c.EstatusID.Equals(estatusid), includeProperties: "Estatus");
```

Problem is   `var estatusid = _estatusService.Listar();` get 0 values, and I don´t know why it don´t get values, can someone help ? Regards

**Methods implementations:**

```
 public virtual IEnumerable<T> Listar(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _dbset;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).AsEnumerable<T>();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.AsEnumerable<T>();
            }
        }

        public virtual T Cargar(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _dbset;
            query = query.AsNoTracking().Where(filter);

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

**UPDATE:**

If I use `.Tolist` as  ***Ivan Stoev*** comment it return all values of Estatus but now it pass to:

```
var tc = _tipoCargaService.Listar(c => c.EstatusID.Equals(estatusid), includeProperties: "Estatus");
```

then it load foreach like:

```
if (tc != null)
                {
                    List<TipoCargaViewModel> tiposcargas = new List<TipoCargaViewModel>();
                foreach (var item in tc)
                {
                    var carga = new TipoCargaViewModel()
                    {
                        ID = item.ID,
                        Nombre = item.Nombre,
                        Descripcion = item.Descripcion,
                        EstatusID = item.EstatusID,
                        NombreEstatus = item.Estatus.Nombre
                    };
                    tiposcargas.Add(carga);
                }
```

But when it try to pass foreach it throw an exception:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Project.Model.Estatus'.
>   Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this
>   context.

Comment: Sounds like a bug is `Listar` method implementation. Which means you need to post that method code.

Comment: Lisatar method is: `IEnumerable<T> Listar(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "");` @IvanStoev

Comment: This is not a method, just signature. We need the **implementation** of that method. In other words, code.

Comment: I´m sorry, I update my question with implementaions @IvanStoev

Comment: No problem. The implementation looks ok. Are you sure `var estatusList = _estatusService.Listar().ToList();` returns empty list?

Comment: Yes it return objects with values now. Can you check my update please @IvanStoev

Comment: Well, in this case the `c => c.EstatusID.Equals(estatusid)` is not a valid criteria because `estatusid` is *collection*, not single value. And you don't need it at all since the FK relationship guarantees that the `EstatusID` is valid value pointing to a record in the `Estatus` table. So use simply `var tc = _tipoCargaService.Listar(includeProperties: "Estatus");` and you are done. Also there is no need to check `if (tc != null)` because `Listar` method never returns `null`. Hope that helps. Happy coding.

Comment: It works. Thanks! @IvanStoev